# Change product status if prices are updated in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, user-roles

I need to change product post_status in a hook. I trying to make product get back to "pending" status everytime vendor change the price.

```
add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'mp_sync_on_product_save', 10, 4 );
function mp_sync_on_product_save( $meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value ) {
    if ( $meta_key == '_price' ) { // edited price
        if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'product' ) {
            $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
            $product['post_status'] = 'pending'; //how to update this?
            // var_dump($product_id);var_dump($product);die('test');

        }
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what function could do this: "$product['post_status'] ='pending';"?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will **change the product status to pending** if anyone else than the "administrator" user role update product prices in backend:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_object_updated_props', 'change_status_on_product_object_updated_prices', 10, 2 );
function change_status_on_product_object_updated_prices( $product, $updated_props ) {

    $changed_props = $product->get_changes();

    if ( $product->get_status() !== 'pending' && ( in_array( 'regular_price', $updated_props, true ) ||
    in_array( 'sale_price', $updated_props, true ) ) && ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) )
    {
        wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => $product->get_id(), 'post_status' => 'pending' ) );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> The "administrator" user role will not be affected by the code… You should also check that "Vendors user role is not able to change the product post status.

Comment: If anyone in 2022 still needs this, in latest wordpress 6.1, woocommerce 6.7.0 with PHP 8 this doesn't work anymore (I don't really know how it was working in 2018 because as far as I know in_array never checked the keys).

The function in Woocommerce 6.7.0 receives only one parameter (Wc product Object) and to check if the price or whatever other prop has been changed, instead of in_array() you should use array_key_exists($needle, $array).