# Change status of woocommerce products by php function

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a function which help me to make a redirect of a product if that product doesn't exist anymore in my affiliate xml.
What I want now is to put the product on draft but to redirect his link to a "This products doesnt exist anymore page" - for seo purposes

I didn't try something because I dont know what.
I saw something here and I think my answear is here but i don't know how to apply it:

[Change product status if prices are updated in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52977326/change-product-status-if-prices-are-updated-in-woocommerce-3)

```
function my_is_post_to_delete( $is_post_to_delete, $post_id, $import ) {
    $redirect_url = "https://stackoverflow.com";
    if ( $import->id == 72 ) {
        $redirects = get_option( '301_redirects', array() );
        $redirects = maybe_unserialize( $redirects );

        $url_for_post = get_the_permalink( $post_id );
        $url = parse_url( $url_for_post );
        if ( $url ) {
            if ( ! array_key_exists( $url['path'], $redirects ) ) {
                $redirects[ $url['path'] ] = $redirect_url;
                update_option( '301_redirects', $redirects );
            }
        }
        return false;       
    }
}
add_filter( 'wp_all_import_is_post_to_delete', 'my_is_post_to_delete', 10, 3 );
```

I expect that my code to remove the product from my website feed and redirect his link to a page of my website.
For seo purposes I cannot delete the product for all I just need to hide it from my shop but keep the link for google (also the pictures).

Answer (score 0):

You can use WordPress function to update the status of the product where your logic of `product doesn't exist anymore in my affiliate xml.` exists.

```
function my_is_post_to_delete( $is_post_to_delete, $post_id, $import ) {
    $redirect_url = "https://stackoverflow.com";
    if ( $import->id == 72 ) {

     /* Start Here*/
     $my_product = array(
          'ID'           => $import->id,
          'post_status' => 'draft',
      );
      wp_update_post( $my_product );
      /* End Here*/

        $redirects = get_option( '301_redirects', array() );
        $redirects = maybe_unserialize( $redirects );

        $url_for_post = get_the_permalink( $post_id );
        $url = parse_url( $url_for_post );
        if ( $url ) {
            if ( ! array_key_exists( $url['path'], $redirects ) ) {
                $redirects[ $url['path'] ] = $redirect_url;
                update_option( '301_redirects', $redirects );
            }
        }
        return false;       
    }
}
add_filter( 'wp_all_import_is_post_to_delete', 'my_is_post_to_delete', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: I don't understand it.. can you complete entire my function with the new code please ?

Comment: the import ID is not the product ID.. I think thats what you are trying ? sorry if I get understand wrong

Comment: I've removed this IF (if ( $import->id == 72 ) {) because I don't need it, is not good. 
I want to apply the function globally, not just for 1 Import ID.